# Detecting makeindex's level specifier

Tags: indexing, makeindex

I am currently writing a small package, and want to write a changelog macro that wraps `\index` similar to:

```tex
\NewDocumentCommand{\changes}{mm}{\index{#1!#2}}
```

However, the level specifier `!` can be changed using the `level` in the index .ist file.
As such, is there an established method of determining the index specifiers?

I know it's possible to determine it via some regex, but that seems ... messy.

Comment: Did you want to scan the `.ist` file?(or whatever file .xxx is being called in) Alternatively, can the user supply non-default values (`{ m O{!} m }`, `\changes[x]{level1}{level2}`)?

Comment: My goal is to automatically determine the current level separator. 
Scanning the `.ist` file is an option, but that is likely unreliable because not every style file will have an `.ist` extension. 

Ideally I am looking for a way that the current level separator is exposed via TeX.

Comment: My understanding (it may be incorrect) is that the `makeindex` script (a C program), outside of TeX, has exposure to the style-setting definitions and values and it does the sorting etc and treats everything as plain text. The alternative indexer, Xindy, is more powerful and flexible, but I would expect, logically, it would also sit in its own space, outside of TeX.

Comment: Yeah you are correct, makeindex and xindy are both standalone executables outside TeX. Though from the sounds of it, it looks like there is not an established (i.e. someone solved this before me) way to get the level separators.